# Have Apache Camel log the URL that is being called

Tags: logging, apache-camel

I have a route that boils down to the following:

```
from("direct:" + routeId)
        .routeId(routeId)
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("${header.path}")).removeHeader("path")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("${header.queryString}")).removeHeader("queryString")
        .toD(COMPONENT_NAME + "://" + myEndpoint + "?" + camelQueryParams)
```

I would like to log the URL and preferably headers that toD ends up sending. If I sends the exchange to the logging component, e.g.

```
.to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
```

it just ends up logging the exchange and I don't get the URL that was called.
Any advice on how to log the URL from toD?

Answer (score 0):

Set a header before sending the message:

```
       .setHeader("URL", simple(COMPONENT_NAME + "://" + myEndpoint + "?" + camelQueryParams))
       .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
       .toD(COMPONENT_NAME + "://" + myEndpoint + "?" + camelQueryParams)
```